# Filter log4j 2.0 messages to separate log files per-webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, log4j2

### Executive Summary

How do I filter by the servlet in which the log message was invoked? (presently using 2.0 beta8)

### Why on earth I would want to do that...

I have several existing web applications. They were written to rely on a proprietary logging system. I have re-implemented a key class from the proprietary system from scratch and added it as a class the proprietary system as a jar and log4j 2.0 as jars in tomcat, thereby utilizing the class loading load order in tomcat to divert the proprietary system into log4j. This succeeds and my log4j config now controls everything (Yay!).

But... (There's always a "But"!)

I was very pleased until I discovered that with all 4 applications deployed in the same container, they were not coordinating their writes to the single log file in the single configuration I had placed in conf/log4j2.xml (and specifed by passing `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/mnt/kui/tomcat/conf/log4j2.xml` on the command line). **I found some log messages with much earlier time stamps (hours earlier) in the middle of the log file.** Out of order logs (and possibly overwritten log lines?) are not desirable of course.

I actually don't want them all in one file anyway and would **prefer a log per application controlled by a single config file**. Initially I thought this would be easy to achieve since log4j automatically sets up a LoggingContext with the name of the web application.

**However I can't seem to find a filter implementation that will allow me to filter on the LoggingContext.** I understand that from each application's perspective there is only one logging context (I think), but the same config file is read by 4 applications so from the config perspective LoggingContext is not unique.

I'm looking for a way to route each application to it's own file without having a config file for every application, or having to add classes to all the applications or edit war files (including web.xml). I'm sooo... close but It's not working.

Just to complicate matters, there is a jar file we wrote that is shared among all 4 applications that uses this logging too and one application has converted to using log4j directly in it's classes (but it still uses proprietary classes that reference the proprietary logging class that I replaced).

I have already seen http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html and my case seems closest to '"Shared" Web Applications and REST Service Containers' but that case doesn't seem very well covered by that page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the RoutingAppender  which can be used to separate log files based on data in your ThreadContextMap. You could use the web app name as a unique key.

About the out of order logs, there was an issue with FastFileAppender in older betas. If append was false, the old file was not truncated but new log events would start to overwrite the old file from the beginning. (So after your most recent log event you would see yesterday's log events, for example). What version are you using?

Comment: Using 2.0beta8, sorry should have said that.

Comment: Gus, take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-326 Expecially Ralph's example config may be useful for understanding how to use the RoutingAppender. About the out of order logs, can you raise a new JIRA ticket for this, that includes your configuration and the problem description? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I can send you a bug report. I blew away that config (and the logs) some time ago. If I see it again I'll try to write a bug for you.